# Spring beans not shown under Spring elements

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am using Juno version of eclipse and have installed STS and i am mainly interested in spring bean search and Bean flow diagram but both are not working.

Nothing is shown under spring elements which implies that STS is not able to detect beans in my project.
But project is working fine.

This post is of no help: [Spring Explorer not showing beans from bean definition file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579710/spring-explorer-not-showing-beans-from-bean-definition-file)
as settings option shown here are not applicable to juno.

Comment: Have U tried in other eclipse version ? Do you used sts installer or eclipse installer?

Comment: Installed it from STS update site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to enable the Spring nature for your existing project. After that, the project properties has a Spring category, in which you can configure the used Spring config files. Once configured, the spring beans model is being built and updated automatically, and you should be able to see the elements in the Spring Explorer as well as use the beans search, etc.